# Where do Apple developer questions go?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, stackexchange-2.0, migration

Over at Apple.SE, if a question isn't getting an answer, and it's Apple developer-related (OS X or iOS) we move it over to Stack Overflow. But sometimes SO moves Apple developer questions over to Apple.SE, and it's immediately apparent at Apple.SE that it won't get an answer there.

The most current example is [iOS - Apple Developer Organization Profile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4975623/ios-apple-developer-organization-profile?noredirect=1).

The Apple.SE rule of thumb has been that if it's developer-related, then it goes to SO.
I can't tell what rule (if any) SO is using. But the end result is that questions are falling between the cracks.

What's to be done?

Comment: Hmmm… I was really hoping that an SO mod would respond to this, as otherwise, nothing will change.

Answer (score 9):

IMO that's not a legitimate move. Even if it was determined that the question wasn't directly related to development (which, IMO, it is), it should have been migrated to Programmers.

Software development questions belong on SO. Apple.SE is designed to answer questions about Apple products, not about software development (even if it's something ADC-related).

Answer (score 2):

That question is a tricky case.  While developer-related, the question being asked is about the specifics of how their company name will be listed on the App Store.

I agree that it doesn't belong on Apple.SE, but I'm not sure that it belongs on Stack Overflow either.  Questions involving the App Store alone aren't dealing with programming problems or developer tools, they are business-related ones about the process of selling or distributing an application.

Typically, I vote to close purely App-Store-related questions as off-topic, and either point people to [Apple's developer forums](https://devforums.apple.com/) or the [iPhone Software Business mailing list](http://groups.google.com/group/iphonesb/), but lately I've seen some of these questions find a home on Programmers.  I'm not sure if they belong there either, but many of them have been not closed and even upvoted there.

Comment: Hi Brad... So, one year later, where do you now think that App Store questions should go, like "am I getting punished [time-wise] for an earlier expedited review?"Etc. Or still no good fit?

Comment: @Yar - Non-programming questions about the App Store or Apple-specific developer sites still don't fit well with Stack Overflow. Programmers has welcomed some of them, but not all. There is an App Stores proposal on Area 51, but even the usefulness of that is being questioned: http://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com/questions/2683/is-the-app-stores-proposal-really-useful . I still generally direct people to Apple's developer forums for review and other related questions, because there are areas set up for that, and many of these problems are temporary or account-specific.